# How to map over useState array of objects and edit the needed object?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [Questions, setQuestions] = React.useState(props.QuestionsData);
  const handleClick = (id, isCorrect) => {
    if (isCorrect) {
      setQuestions((prev) => {
        prev.map((item, index) => {
          if (index === id) {
            return {
              ...item,
              [item.Answers.correct.selected]: !item.Answers.correct.selected,
            };
          } else {
            return item;
          }
        });
      });
    } else {
      return;
    }
  };
```

This is the code im doing and what I want to do it loop over the Questions (which has a list of objects that look like this.

```
{
  "category": "Entertainment: Video Games",
  "type": "boolean",
  "difficulty": "hard",
  "question": "The first &quot;Metal Gear&quot; game was released for the PlayStation 1.",
  "correct_answer": "False",
  "incorrect_answers": [
      "True"
  ],
  "Answers": {
      "correct": {
          "MasterId": "MXTOfKnKw7dU7QP0UP0td",
          "id": 0,
          "answer": "False",
          "selected": false,
          "correct": true,
          "userChosen": true
      },
      "wrong": {
          "id": 1,
          "answer": "True",
          "selected": false
      }
  }
}
```

I tried to do everything but it returns undefined. I even tried to do the map alone with the value and logged out the needed value and it worked.

If someone can tell me a good way to loop over `usestate` array of objects and only edit the objects that satisfy the condition that would be great.

Comment: You need to return the `prev.map()`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the curly braces so that the value is actually returned.

```js
setQuestions((prev) =>
    prev.map((item, index) => {
        if (index === id) {
            return {
                ...item,
                [item.Answers.correct.selected]: !item.Answers.correct.selected,
            };
        } else {
            return item;
        }
    });
);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't recommend using the capitalization convention for variable names. Use camelCase and save those for Components, Classes, and Types.
2. For the sake of readability and clean code, I recommend you write data processing code outside of `setSomeState()`

Here's an example.

```js
import { useState } from "react";
...

const [questionList, setQuestionList] = useState(props.questionsData);

const handleClick = (id, isCorrect) => {
  if (isCorrect) {
    const updatedList = questionList.map((item, index) => {
      if (index === id) {
        return {
          ...item,
          [item.answers.correct.selected]: !item.answers.correct.selected,
        };
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    });
    // no messy prev state stuff, it's now clean and easy to maintain
    setQuestionList(updatedList);
  } else {
    return;
  }
};
```

Further, I see that you use `props.questionData` as a default value of the setState. It's not a good approach since one component's state's default value depends on the other component's value and can potentially cause errors.

I personally recommend you to keep the `questions` default state to an empty array, and use `useEffect` and do `setQuestions` inside the `useEffect` with `props.questionData`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you imagine writing this handler every time you have array-based stated? Also `map` doesn't make sense because we only want to update *one* item, however `map` iterates over the entire array.

Write a generic function to `update` an `arr` at a specific `index` using a user-supplied `func` -

```js
function update(arr, index, func) {
  return [
    ...arr.slice(0, index),
    func(arr[index]),
    ...arr.slice(index + 1)
  ]
}
```

Now in your component -

```js
function MyComponent({ questions = [] }) {

  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState(questions)

  const updateQuestion = index => event =>
    setQuestions(arr => update(arr, index, q => ({
       /* update q here */
    })))

  return questions.map((q, index) =>
    <Question key={index} question={q} onClick={updateQuestion(index)} />
  )
}
```

Developing your own utility functions to operate on arrays and objects can be a fun exercise, but maybe challenging to get right. Look to popular libraries like Immutable.js and Immer for inspiration.

See these Q&A for live examples you can run in your browser -

- [Add Numbers in ReactJS without button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74911269/633183)
- [How to change Active when it is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74911047/633183)
- [How to remove an element from an array passing the key using hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74901715/633183)
- [how to add class and remove class from buttons in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73763261/633183)

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to return the result of the map. If a function doesn't return anything in JS, `undefined` will be returned. In addition, the computed property isn't used correctly here:

```
{
   ...item,
   [item.Answers.correct.selected]: !item.Answers.correct.selected,
}
```

Try this:

```
const handleClick = (id, isCorrect) => {
    if (isCorrect) {
      setQuestions((prev) =>
        prev.map((item, index) => {
           if (index === id) {
              item.Answers.correct.selected = !item.Answers.correct.selected
           }
           return item
        }));
    }
  };
```